# How can I prove that this matrix is nonsingular?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

How can I prove that $
\begin{vmatrix} 
\frac{1}{(x_1-y_1)^2} & \frac{1}{(x_1-y_2)^2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{(x_1-y_n)^2} \\
\frac{1}{(x_2-y_1)^2} & \frac{1}{(x_2-y_2)^2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{(x_2-y_n)^2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{(x_n-y_1)^2} & \frac{1}{(x_n-y_2)^2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{(x_n-y_n)^2}
\end{vmatrix} \ne 0
$?

For $x_i$ and $y_i$ are all distinct.

Comment: Is there any unspecified assumptions about $x_i$ and $y_i$, such as $x_i$ are all distinct?

Comment: If $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ then you fail for $n=2$.

Comment: Usually, what one does is to fix the values for $y$ (all distinct because otherwise the matrix is singular), clear your fractions, find the degree of the corresponding polynomial in the $x_i$'s and try to see if there are enough obvious answers to to the polynomial to account for all the easy solutions.

Comment: We need all $x_i$ and all $y_j$ to be distinct.  If $x_i =x_k$ for some $i,k$, then two of the rows would be identical and so the determinant would be zero.  The same follows for the $y_j$'s except that two or more columns would be identical.

Answer (score 3):

Even if all the $x_i$ and $y_j$ are distinct, this is not true.

For instance, if $x_1=2/3$, $x_2=2$, $y_1=1$, $y_2=0$, we have
$$
\begin{vmatrix}\frac1{(x_1-y_1)^2}&\frac1{(x_1-y_2)^2}\\\frac1{(x_2-y_1)^2}&\frac1{(x_2-y_2)^2}\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac1{(2/3-1)^2}&\frac1{(2/3-0)^2}\\
\frac1{(2-1)^2}&\frac1{(2-0)^2}
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
9&9/4\\
1&1/4
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$